# multiple data sources to one table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 (or more) tables of the same data from many sources.  What I need to do is match up the columns and make one table.  For example:

TABLE 1

```
ColA, ColB, ColC
----- ----- -----
REd, 1, 4
Green, 3, 4
```

TABLE 2

```
COLA, COLB, COLC
----- ----- -----
Fred, A, C
Wilma, Z, H
```

New table

```
COLA, COLB, COLC
----- ----- -----
REd, 1, 4
Green, 3, 4
Fred, A, C
Wilma, Z, H
```

I just need to know how to relate the columns together - any tips?

Comment: **(1)** No shouting in the title please; also, formatting and proofreading would go a long way here.  **(2)** This has nothing to do with MySQL apparently, no need for the tag.  **(3)**  Use a `UNION`, and convert any inconsistent data types to a consistent data type (ColC as a varchar, for example)  **(4)** Are you trying to insert into a table, or simply select records?  Question is kind of vague.

Comment: If colA=COLA and ColB=COLB and ColC=COLC do you want to have all the other cols in one row or do you want to add them together by row? In SQL Language are you trying to combing columns and make a single row or are you combining rows?

Comment: Hi there, the datatypes are the same.  ultimately I want table 1ColA and table2 COLA, to be in the same column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM Table2 
UNION ALL
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM Table3
```

Comment: @LeoCatt, please Accept an answer that worked for you by clicking the outlined checkmark.